# Analyzing prime number output in Java. Not getting output as expected

Tags: java

```
public class Chpt5_Project{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare Variables
    int randomNumbers = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    //Loop for number generation and print out numbers
    System.out.print("The five random numbers are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        randomNumbers = (int)(Math.random()*20);
        sum += randomNumbers;

        if (i == 4) {
            System.out.println("and " + randomNumbers + ".");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(randomNumbers + ", ");
        }
    }
    //Display Sum
    System.out.println("\nThe sum of these five numbers is " + sum + ".\n");

 // Test if number is prime
    boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= sum / 2; divisor++) 
        if (sum % divisor == 0) { // If true, number is not prime
            isPrime = false; // Set isPrime to false

             System.out.println("The sum is not a prime number.");}
        else {
                 System.out.println("The sum is a prime number.");
          break;
      }

   }
}
```

Sample output

> The five random numbers are: 5, 0, 10, 6, and 13.
>
> The sum of these five numbers is 34.
>
> The sum is not a prime number. The sum is a prime number.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question... code dump without explaining what it is you're trying to do is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, I am still new to this. I am not understanding why I get the output from both print lines when the number result is not a prime number. when the result is a prime number the output is as expected. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your original question with all this information.

Comment: Your indentation is horrendous, and likely the reason why your logic is wrong, because you can't easily see the program flow. You should `break` when you set `isPrime = false`, and then print after the loop ends.

Comment: It did not copy and paste correctly is part of the issue, the rest is that I am still very much new to this. I apreciate you taking the time to give me your input, I am fixing the indentation now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **parenthesis** of the `for-loop` and then add `break` statement inside `if-statement`.

```
for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= sum / 2; divisor++){

        if (sum % divisor == 0) { // If true, number is not prime
              isPrime = false; // Set isPrime to false
              System.out.println("The sum is not a prime number.");
              break;
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("The sum is a prime number.");
             break;
         }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like this fixed my issue. Much appreciated!